# SQL Server report 2 series on the same chart

Tags: sql-server, charts, report, series

This should be simple but the answer eludes me.

I have a basic table

| Color value | Color | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | green | 00:00 |
| 11 | green | 00:01 |
| 9 | red | 00:01 |
| 12 | green | 00:02 |
| 11 | red | 00:02 |
| 13 | green | 00:03 |
| 10 | red | 00:03 |

I need to create a chart, time on the horizontal and value on the vertical. However I need 2 series, one green and one red, on the same chart.

I don't know how to put both of them in the same dataset

Comment: Expected results would be useful here.

Comment: Not likely to get much help without knowing what reporting package you are using in your application - details of which you did not tag. I would expect your reporting product to use 2 different datasets (i.e., queries) and effectively overlay them.